# Mobile Chrome ignoring responsive images

Tags: image, mobile, responsive-design

Long time browser, first time caller....

I have recently re-written my website to use responsive images (which I am new to), but my s7 chrome seems to always load the "medium" sized image, which is the default src.

I have tried clearing cache and using incognito. It still appears that the medium image is loading, although the only way I'm deducing that is by selecting the image and loading in a new tab and reading the url. I'm not sure if this is accurate.

I've also tried changing the default src to the small image, but the medium is still loading.

However, on FF and Chrome desktop, even with developer tools set to mobile device, it seems to work correctly. Here's the relevant code:

```
<img
    class="vertical"
    src="../galleryphotos/doveinsnow_medium.jpg"
    sizes=" (max-width: 675px) 271px,
            (max-width: 1920px) 620px,
            (min-width: 1921px) 1240px,
            100vw"
    srcset="../galleryphotos/doveinsnow_small.jpg 271w,
            ../galleryphotos/doveinsnow_medium.jpg 620w,
            ../galleryphotos/doveinsnow_large.jpg 1240w"
            alt="Dove In Snow photograph"/>
```

Here is a link to the page with the above image, although every page on the site behaves the same way:
http://herschbachphotography.com/gallery_index/doveinsnow.html

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, everything is working well. I checked with Chrome Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) and I can see all 3 versions of your image if I change the viewport from 675px to more than 1920px.

Here are 2 ways you could confirm which image is being shown.

If you place a different marker on each of the 3 images it will be easy to tell which one is being displayed.

Another way is to use [Web Inspector](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/#get-started) (from within your browser, right click on your page then choose 'inspect')

Click the network tab, select img, then reload the page. You'll get full details of all the images on the page.

I hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It does work in desktop Chrome & FF, but it doesn't appear to work on my mobile chrome. It seems to be loading the medium size. I'm judging that based on the time it takes to display the image (I see it render from top to bottom in a second or two), and the fact that I can open image in new browser and the url is for the medium image. Unfortunately there aren't any mobile tools that I know of to diagnose. Can you confirm the medium image loading on your mobile? Is there even a way to do that?

Comment: To be clear, when I say desktop Chrome & FF, I'm changing the viewport sizes and also using the mobile "mode". It does work. On my actual phone, it does not, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ohhhh, I just re-read your comment and caught the different marker part. Not sure why I didn't think of that. I'll give that a go.

Comment: Okay, I created a test page which is a copy of the doveinsnow, but with marked images (L)arge, (M)edium, (S)mall, and I did a (Mobile) one for the header image.

On my phone, Chrome, the Large header image is showing and the Medium doveinsnow is showing. However, on the desktop Chrome, the images swap correctly. Not sure what's going on.

http://herschbachphotography.com/gallery_index/imagetest.html

Comment: Hi @TimHerschbach, good going with the marked images. To isolate what's happening I created a codepen @ https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/zJQZXo . If you make the viewport very narrow then gradually increase it the images clearly change from S ==> M ==> L . As far as I can see the logic for what you've done is good, yet when I preview this pen on my phone I too only see the M, and not the expected S image.  I'll sleep on it ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, I also verified on my wife's iPhone, an S5, and an S3 that the same thing is happening... the banner image is showing up as "S" but should be "Mobile" and the "M" should be "S". I'm new to SO so I'm not sure if I can post more code, but I can post my entire css if needed.